# Symfony2 - Customizing buttons out of forms

Tags: forms, symfony, button

I have problem with forms and page layouts. I render my page by:

```
{% block body -%}
{{ form(edit_form, {'style': 'horizontal'}) }}
    <ul class="record_actions">
        <li>
            <a href="{{ path('organization') }}">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Back to the list</button>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            {{ form(delete_form) }}
        </li>
    </ul>
 {% endblock %}
```

I have some style on ul record_actions. It looks like this: http://postimg.org/image/sby8jnojz/

My problem is with update button. I would like to put it into `<ul>` tags with 2 other buttons. Is there some possibility to put it outside of form? I like, how the form looks with `{{ form(edit_form, {'style': 'horizontal'}) }}`. So I wouldn't like to customize every part by `{{form_widget}}`. Or is there possibility to render all form and then render just this button?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Let's take a hypothetical controller method - where I have defined two forms `edit_form` and `delete_form`. Don't worry about these too much, they are just proof of concept. The important thing here is that I have two forms that I am sending to the template to be rendered:

```
// Foo\BarBundle\Controller\BazController
public function editAction()
{
    // a placeholder 'edit' form
    $editForm = $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('name', 'text')
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('send', 'submit')
        ->getForm();

    // a placeholder 'delete' form
    $deleteForm = $this->createFormBuilder(['id' => 1])
        ->add('id', 'hidden')
        ->getForm();

    // assign form views to template
    return [
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ];
}
```

Next the template. We have two forms to render: `edit_form` and `delete_form`. There are a couple of issues we need to consider - rendering a form within a form is *not allowed* so we cannot render `delete_form` inside `edit_form` or vice versa.

However we can, as I explained below, with the HTML5 `form` attribute place form elements outside of a `<form>` context and still link them to that form (with the aforementioned IE* limitations). So let's do that, and suggest a workaround in due course.

The least invasive thing to do is to render the `delete_form` after the `edit_form` but place the `edit_form` delete button *inside* `edit_form`.

I don't know if you are using a CSS framewok to help you with layout - I am assuming Bootstrap 2.* here so you might have to update your markup - either way the idea should be clear enough:

```
<div class="row">
    {{ form_start(edit_form, {'attr': {'id': 'edit-form'}}) }}
    <div class="span4">
        <ul class="record_actions">
            <li>{{ form_widget(edit_form.send)}}</li>
            <li><button id="delete-form-submit" form="delete-form">
                Delete
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        {{ form_rest(edit_form) }}
    </div>
    {{ form_end(edit_form) }}
</div>

{{ form(delete_form, {'attr': {'id': 'delete-form'}, 'method': 'GET'}) }}
```

The above HTML yields a layout similar to the following:

[image]

A few points of explanation:

1. I have created a two-column layout for the form. The `.record_actions` buttons are rendered on the left column - this is essential - but they are floated right using Bootstrap's `.pull-right` in this case.

   2. **Update button**: the first thing I want to do is render the `submit` button in `ul.record_actions` where I want it: `<li>{{ form_widget(edit_form.send)}}</li>`
   3. **Delete button**: I have not defined a `submit` button on the `delete_form` because I want to explicitly create it outside of the context of the `delete_form`, instead placing it where I have. Note that I defined a form attribute on this element called `delete-form`. This links this element to `delete_form` instead of `edit_form`: `<li><button id="delete-form-submit" form="delete-form">Delete</button></li>`
   4. **Remaining fields**: in the second column I can dump all the remaining `edit_form` fields implicitly with `{{ form_rest(edit_form) }}`, as per **@Kix**'s suggestion!
   5. **Delete form** Finally, we render the `delete_form` *outside* the `edit_form` with `{{ form(delete_form, {'attr': {'id': 'delete-form'}, 'method': 'GET'}) }}`. A couple of things to note here - we are explicitly adding an id for the form with `{'attr': {'id': 'delete-form'}`. This is important as it is the attribute that the delete button refers to. In this case I also added `'method': 'GET'` to test on my machine. You will probably want to leave this out (in  which case it defaults to `POST`)

There you have it... This should help you define your preferred layout.

But, we still need to address IE. If you are using jQuery, you could add a click handler to the delete button, which we've assigned the id `#delete-form-submit`. Note that the following is a suggestion and is not tested:

```
$(function() {
  if ($.browser.msie) { // @see: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/
    $('#delete-form-submit').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#delete-form').submit();
    });
  });
});
```

Now you need to worry about IE users with JS disabled... or not! ;) Hope this helps.

---

**Original answer**

I would argue that your issue is possible Symfony agnostic... Let me explain:

Do you create your form's `submit` button with the form builder? I assume so since you do not explicitly create one in the twig snippet you pasted above.

This is totally fine of course. I usually just define my Twig form templates like so, which I gather is the older way to do it (since the 2.4 docs don't appear to suggest the following):

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ path('foo_edit') }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

This way is totally acceptable in my view - you just don't define the `submit` button.

Of course this does not solve your problem, because you want to "break out" of the form. But you can actually do this with HTML5 with the `form` attribute, which allows you to link disparate tags to a specific tag. A generic example:

```
<form id="foo">
    <label>Username</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
</form>
<ul>
    <li><input type="submit" form="foo">
</ul>
```

Note that the `submit` button is outside `form#foo` but the `form` attribute still links to it.

Obviously its usefulness is restricted to the range of browsers you want to support, as it's a HTML5 feature.

**EDIT**

I checked - it has pretty wide browser support, except.... *drumroll* IE. Up to and including IE10 apparently. I would assume that this is a dealbreaker unfortunately.

**kix**'s approach above could work well however, print out the individual form widgets you want explicitly and then use `form_rest`. I would add to this and say it might not exactly work with the HTML layout you have above - iirc you have to print out any fields explicitly *before* you call `form_rest`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It sounds very good to me. But i had some problem. I don't really know which parametr in input tag I have to use. (`<input form="?">`). I tried to see which parametr use with `{{ form(edit_form) }}`, but without success.

Comment: HI. Okay, I am not familiar with the `{{ form(edit_form) }} syntax - I prefer the approach above. Either way is fine of course. Anyway, I am looking into this for you to see if I can make a further suggestion. I think I can provide an answer - with some caveats. One moment...

Comment: I tried your form creation as well, but also I haven't managed well. Because, when I click on the button, it redirects me into the same page after update, but symfony doesn't have variables from controller in view, that I send them to view.

Comment: It's exactly, what I wanted. Thnak you for your wide reply!

Comment: No problem - it's what SO is for :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 3):

You can always render some widgets in places specific to your layout using

```
{{ form_widget(delete_form.yourWidgetName) }}
```

and then let Symfony complete the form with

```
{{ form_rest(delete_form) }}
```